Why are my native modules not found on JS Engine production build?
I am developing my first native modules, for iOS & Android.  On iOS, I have no problems.  On Android, the development build works fine.  However, when I bundle for production build, the app crashes.  I think it's related to this error in adb logcat:
2024-12-08 20:49:20.531 29294-29339 ReactNativeJS           com.identafly.preview                E  Error: Cannot find native module 'BoundingBox', js engine: hermes
2024-12-08 20:49:20.537 29294-29340 AndroidRuntime          com.identafly.preview                E  FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
                                                                                                    Process: com.identafly.preview, PID: 29294
                                                                                                    com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Error: Cannot find native module 'BoundingBox', js engine: hermes, stack:
                                                                                                    requireNativeModule@1:688911

What could be different between dev & production bundles in the way it imports my android content:
// expo-module.config.json
{
  "platforms": ["ios", "tvos", "android", "web"],
  "ios": {
    "modules": ["BoundingBoxModule"]
  },
  "android": {
    "modules": ["expo.modules.boundingbox.BoundingBoxModule"]
  }
}

which references my JS module layer:
// modules/bounding-box/index.ts
import { type BoundingBoxProps } from './src/BoundingBox.types';
// Import the native module. On web, it will be resolved to BoundingBox.web.ts
// and on native platforms to BoundingBox.ts
import BoundingBoxModule from './src/BoundingBoxModule';

const drawBoundingBox = (props?: BoundingBoxProps) => {
  if (
    BoundingBoxModule &&
    typeof BoundingBoxModule.drawBoundingBox === 'function'
  ) {
    BoundingBoxModule.drawBoundingBox(props?.boundingBox, props?.color);
  } else {
    console.error('drawBoundingBox method not found');
  }
};

export { BoundingBoxProps, drawBoundingBox };

and the native require:
// modules/bounding-box/src/BoundingBoxModule.ts
import { requireNativeModule } from 'expo-modules-core';

// It loads the native module object from the JSI or falls back to
// the bridge module (from NativeModulesProxy) if the remote debugger is on.
export default requireNativeModule('BoundingBox');

Is there something different between dev & prod JS bundles?  Something else?

I faced the same issue while building a React Native Expo app for production that included a local native module, but the module wasn’t being bundled.
I was using these command:
eas build --profile production --platform android --local
eas build --profile development --platform android --local
Surprisingly, the solution for me was to ensure that the /modules/module-name/android and /modules/module-name/ios folders were not ignored by git. It seems counterintuitive, but after making sure these folders were tracked by git, everything worked as expected.
I hope this helps you resolve the issue too! Let me know if you need further clarification.

thanks , i will double check as it definitely crossed my mind and AFAIK, they are not ignored...
